# How to avoid the key binding delay when alternating quickly between two keys

Tags: java, swing, input, keyboard-events, keyevent

Here is my problem : When I change quickly between two keys, it blocks half a second between both (for example with two keys, a left and a right key that are used to move the game character, firstly I click on the left key, then I want to switch quickly to the right key, and even if the time that I took to switch is pretty little, it will anyway stop my game character for ~0.5s until it move right).
Example in this [short video](https://youtu.be/OSrs-XJnlcw)

I am actually not able to find any way to use properly the keyboard inputs in a game to stop that weird problem. 
The own thing I finally found after hours of researches is this topic : [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67801/is-the-key-bindings-delay-unavoidable-in-java-when-pressing-different-directiona), and as the author seems to say, there is no way to know if it will work after all the changes to the project that I would have to do in order to implement that JInput library.

Here is the part of the code that use keyboard inputs:

```
class MainClient {
private static String clientName;
private static GameClient gameClient;
private static List<Object> allSolidObjects = new ArrayList<>();
private static boolean stopRight = false, stopLeft = false;
private static GameFrame gameFrame;
private static Character character;
private static CharacterView characterView;
private static final String MOVE_LEFT = "move left", MOVE_RIGHT = "move right", MOVE_STOP = "move stop";
private static final int FPS = 60;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            character = new Character();
            characterView = new CharacterView(
                    character.getRelativeX(),
                    character.getRelativeY(),
                    Character.getRelativeWidth(),
                    Character.getRelativeHeight());

            gameFrame.getGamePanel().setCharacterView(characterView);

            final InputMap IM = gameFrame.getGamePanel().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            final ActionMap AM = gameFrame.getGamePanel().getActionMap();
            MovementState movementState = new MovementState();

            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, 0, true), MOVE_STOP);
            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), MOVE_STOP);
            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), MOVE_STOP);
            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), MOVE_STOP);
            AM.put(MOVE_STOP, new MoveXAction(movementState, 0f));

            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), MOVE_RIGHT);
            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), MOVE_RIGHT);
            AM.put(MOVE_RIGHT, new MoveXAction(movementState, Character.getRelativeSpeed()));

            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, 0, false), MOVE_LEFT);
            IM.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), MOVE_LEFT);
            AM.put(MOVE_LEFT, new MoveXAction(movementState, -Character.getRelativeSpeed()));
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000/FPS, e -> {
                if (movementState.xDirection < 0) {
                    stopRight = false;
                    if (!stopLeft) {
                        character.setRelativeX(character.getRelativeX() + movementState.xDirection);
                        for (Object object : allSolidObjects) {
                            if (CollisionDetection.isCollisionBetween(character, object)) {
                                stopLeft = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (movementState.xDirection > 0) {
                    stopLeft = false;
                    if (!stopRight) {
                        character.setRelativeX(character.getRelativeX() + movementState.xDirection);
                        for (Object object : allSolidObjects) {
                            if (CollisionDetection.isCollisionBetween(character, object)) {
                                stopRight = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                characterView.setRelativeX(character.getRelativeX());
                characterView.setRelativeY(character.getRelativeY());
                gameFrame.getGamePanel().setCharacterView(characterView);

                gameFrame.getGamePanel().repaint();
            });
            timer.start();

        });
    }
}

// Not important method
private static void launchGameClient() {}

static class MoveXAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final MovementState movementState;
    private final float value;

    MoveXAction(MovementState movementState, float value) {
        this.movementState = movementState;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.movementState.xDirection = this.value;
    }
}

static class MovementState {
    float xDirection;
}
}
```

And if you want to test it by yourself to see the problem, the full project is on GitHub : 
[here](https://github.com/ThomasCloarec/PlaNetShooter)

So, is there anyone that know how to stop that problem, maybe it's just like that, an OS problem that can't be solved but even if it's the case, please leave an answer and tell it ^^.

Comment: The error is your logic. If you press one button, then another (you have two active keys), then release one, you end up with a “none” state, then you have to wait for is initial press state before the repeat state kicks in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is your logic. If you press one button, then another (you have two active keys), then release one, you end up with a “none” state, then you have to wait for is initial press state before the repeat state kicks in

So, for example...

- Press <kbd>Left</kbd> (`MOVE_LEFT`)
- Press <kbd>Right</kbd> (`MOVE_RIGHT`)
- Release <kbd>Left</kbd> (`MOVE_NONE`)
- Delay between initial press of <kbd>Right</kbd> and repeat event occurs where nothing happens

A better idea is too setup a state where "none" is the absence of a "active" state and not a state.

For this, I use a `Direction` `enum`...

```
public static enum Direction {
    LEFT(-1), RIGHT(1);

    private int delta;

    private Direction(int delta) {
        this.delta = delta;
    }

    public int getDelta() {
        return delta;
    }

}
```

*I've pre-seeded the delta, but you don't "have" to do this, but it does demonstrate a possibly simple implementation*

I then use a `Set` to manage the state...

```
private Set<Direction> movement = new TreeSet<>();
```

When a key is pressed, the corresponding `enum` is added and when released it is removed.

This is done through a "press" and "release" `Action`...

```
static public class PressAction extends AbstractAction {

    private final Set<Direction> movement;
    private final Direction value;

    public PressAction(Set<Direction> movementState, Direction value) {
        this.movement = movementState;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        movement.add(value);
    }
}
static public class ReleaseAction extends AbstractAction {

    private final Set<Direction> movement;
    private final Direction value;

    public ReleaseAction(Set<Direction> movementState, Direction value) {
        this.movement = movementState;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        movement.remove(value);
    }
}
```

This means, so long as the `enum` exists in the `Set`, its delta should be applied.

A nice side effect of this is, if you hold down both the left and right keys, the deltas cancel each other out

## Runnable example...

So, I stripped back you "example" and turned into a runnable example which demonstrates the basic principle.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static enum Direction {
        LEFT(-1), RIGHT(1);

        private int delta;

        private Direction(int delta) {
            this.delta = delta;
        }

        public int getDelta() {
            return delta;
        }

    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int xPos = 95;

        private Set<Direction> movement = new TreeSet<>();

        public TestPane() {
            final InputMap im = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            final ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, 0, true), "Release.left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "Release.left");

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true), "Release.right");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "Release.right");

            am.put("Release.left", new ReleaseAction(movement, Direction.LEFT));
            am.put("Release.right", new ReleaseAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT));

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false), "Press.right");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "Press.right");
            am.put("Press.right", new PressAction(movement, Direction.RIGHT));

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Q, 0, false), "Press.left");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "Press.left");
            am.put("Press.left", new PressAction(movement, Direction.LEFT));

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, e -> {
                for (Direction dir :  movement) {
                    xPos += dir.getDelta();
                }
                repaint();
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillRect(xPos, 95, 10, 10);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    private static final Instant ANCHOR = Instant.now();
    private static Instant switchAd = Instant.now();

    protected static long switchDelay() {
        return Duration.between(switchAd, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }

    protected static long tick() {
        return Duration.between(ANCHOR, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }

    static public class PressAction extends AbstractAction {

        private final Set<Direction> movement;
        private final Direction value;

        public PressAction(Set<Direction> movementState, Direction value) {
            this.movement = movementState;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movement.add(value);
        }
    }
    static public class ReleaseAction extends AbstractAction {

        private final Set<Direction> movement;
        private final Direction value;

        public ReleaseAction(Set<Direction> movementState, Direction value) {
            this.movement = movementState;
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movement.remove(value);
        }
    }

}
```